# use ConfigurationManager to store user values in a file that is separate from the app config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, config, configurationmanager, app-config

Ok, I've just about given up on this.

I would like to be able to record user preferences using a user config file, which would be referenced from the app config file.  I am trying to do this with `ConfigurationManager` and an app config file.  I can read just fine from the user settings, but setting them is a whole other problem.  I would like to keep the app settings separate from the user settings in two different files.

---

---

When I use this:

```
<appSettings file="user.config">
  </appSettings>
```

and user.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="localSetting" value="localVal"/>
</appSettings>
```

I can use ConfigurationManager to READ the local setting, but not to save to the file.

```
var oldLocVal = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["localSetting"]; 
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("localSetting", "newLocalValue"); // Doesn't save to file.
```

---

---

If instead my user.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="localSetting" value="localVal"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I would then like to call and save the AppSettings in this way:

```
var uMap = new ConfigurationFileMap("user.config");
var uConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(uMap);
var oldLocalVarFromConfig = uConfig.AppSettings.Settings["localSetting"]; // NO
uConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("localSetting");                      // NO
uConfig.AppSettings.Settings.Add("localSetting", "newValue");
uConfig.Save();
```

but it won't let me access the configuration's app settings.  (It has a problem casting something as an AppSettings)

---

---

I also tried with `configSource` instead of `file` attributes in the app config `appSettings` element.

I was using the [examples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for help, but unfortunately it wasn't enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load external config files into a 'Configuration' instance. Here is an example of a singleton class with a static constructor that uses this strategy. You can tweak it a bit to do what you want, I think.

```
  private const string _path = @"E:\WhateverPath\User.config"

  static ConfigManager()        
    { 
        ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap()          
        { 
            ExeConfigFilename = _path
        }; 

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        // get some custom configuration section
        _someConfigSection = config.GetSection("SomeSection") as SomeSection; 

        // or just get app settings 
        _appSettingSection = config.AppSettings; 
    }
```

Maybe try adding this way, making sure to call Save()

```
_appSettingSection.Settings.Add("SomeKey", "SomeValue"); 

//make sure to call save
config.Save();
```

Comment: Great, apparently I'd tried OpenExeConfiguration and OpenMappedMachineConfiguration, but THIS is the one that works.

Answer (score 0):

To its credit, [this code here works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194876/redirect-configurationmanager-to-another-file).

Also, I made a simple XML serializable object that saved itself to disk any time Save was called on it.